# How to derive the projection operator for multiple spins in terms of spin operators?

Tags: quantum-spin

Say I have two spin-s angular momenta, $\vec S_1$ and $\vec S_2$.
The Hilbert space is formed by states like
$\left|j,m\right>$, where $0 \leq j \leq 2s$ and for a given $j$ the other quantum number $m$ has $2j+1$ number of labels, i.e, $-j \leq m \leq j$.
I want to construct the all the projection operator $P_j$ that projects a state onto the subspace with total spin quantum number $j$.
The projector
$$
P_j = \sum_{m=-j}^{j}\left|j,m\right>\left<j,m\right|
$$
There is also other way of writing the projection operators in terms of spin operators.
For two spin-1/2 I can have the three projection operator as follows:
$$
P_0 = 1/4 - \vec S_1 \cdot \vec S_2\\
P_1 = 3/4 + \vec S_1 \cdot \vec S_2
$$
These operators project to $j=0,1$ subspace respectively. How these projection operators are derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are restricting to the space of two spin-1/2 particles, then the reason goes as follows. (We set $\hbar=1$.)

It is a fact that
$$
\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(S^2-S_1^2-S_2^2\right)\,,
$$
where $\vec{S}=\vec{S}_1+\vec{S}_2$ is the total spin of the two particles.  This follows by expanding
$$
S^2=\vec{S}\cdot\vec{S}=(\vec{S}_1+\vec{S}_2)\cdot(\vec{S}_1+\vec{S}_2)\,.
$$
Acting with this operator on the coupled state $\lvert s_1s_2,sm \rangle$ state, we get
$$
\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\lvert s_1s_2,sm \rangle
=\frac{1}{2}\left(S^2-S_1^2-S_2^2\right)\lvert s_1s_2,sm \rangle
=\frac{1}{2}\left(s^2-s_1^2-s_2^2\right)\lvert s_1s_2,sm \rangle\,.
$$
Then, since $s_1=1/2$, $s_2=1/2$, and the two-spin-1/2 space can be decomposed as a direct sum of a spin-0 space and a spin-1 space, i.e., $s=0$ and $s=1$, we get two cases for the above expression:
$$
\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle
=\frac{1}{2}\left(0(0+1)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\right)\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle
=-\frac{3}{4}\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle\,,
$$
and
$$
\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle
=\frac{1}{2}\left(1(1+1)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\right)\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle
=\frac{1}{4}\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle\,.
$$
Since the states $\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle$ form a basis for the 1/2+1/2 space, this completely determines the action of $\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2$.  Then, note that
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{4} - \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\right)\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle
&=\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\right)\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle = 0\,,\\
\left(\frac{1}{4} - \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\right)\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle
&=\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{-3}{4}\right)\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle = \lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle\,,\\
\left(\frac{3}{4} - \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\right)\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle
&=\left(\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\right)\lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle = \lvert s_1s_2,0m \rangle\,,\\
\left(\frac{3}{4} + \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\right)\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle
&=\left(\frac{3}{4} + \frac{-3}{4}\right)\lvert s_1s_2,1m \rangle = 0\,,\\
\end{align}
and we can see that these operators have the properties of projection operators.

We can also show that, e.g., $\left(\frac{1}{4} - \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4} - \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2$, so that it is *a* projection operator, but I think we'd still have to act on states to show which space it projects onto.

Answer (score 2):

> The projector
> $$
> P_j = \sum_{m=-j}^{j}\left|j,m\right>\left<j,m\right|
> $$...

> For two spin-1/2 I can have the three projection operator as follows:
> $$
> P_0 = 1/4 - \vec S_1 \cdot \vec S_2\\
> P_1 = 3/4 + \vec S_1 \cdot \vec S_2
> $$

> These operators project to $j=0,1$ subspace respectively. How these projection operators are derived?

For the case you are considering, "[f]or two spin-1/2... j=0, 1 subspace respectively," you can show that
$$
\frac{1}{4} - \vec S_1\cdot\vec S_2 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}S^2\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\frac{3}{4}+ \vec S_1\cdot\vec S_2 = \frac{1}{2}S^2\;.\tag{2}
$$

Recall that the value of $S^2$ is $s(s+1)$, where $s=0$ for the singlet and $s=1$ for the triplet.

Clearly, the operator in Eq. (1) is zero whenever the spin is $s=1$ since
$$
1-\frac{1}{2}1(1+1) = 1-1 = 0
$$
and the operator in Eq. (1) is one whenever the spin is $s=0$ since
$$
1-\frac{1}{2}0(0+1) = 1-0 = 1\;.
$$

Clearly, the operator in Eq. (2) is zero whenever the spin is $s=0$ since
$$
\frac{1}{2}0(1+0) = 0
$$
and the operator in Eq. (2) is one whenever the spin is $s=1$ since
$$
\frac{1}{2}1(1+1) = 1\;.
$$

---

In the general case, you can write a matrix for the projector $P_j$ in the initial basis by using Clebsch-Gordan coefficients:
$$
|jm\rangle = \sum_{m_1, m_2}|m_1, m_2\rangle C_{m_1, m_2, j, m}\;,
$$
to find:
$$
P_j = \sum_{m=-j}^j \sum_{m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2}|m_1,m_2\rangle\langle n_1, n_2| C_{m_1, m_2, j, m}C^*_{n_1, n_2, j, m}\;.
$$

For example, for the case of two spin-1/2 particles combining into the $j=m=0$ state, the projector is:
$$
P_0 = |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle\uparrow\downarrow|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle\downarrow\uparrow|
\right)
+
|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle\uparrow\downarrow|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle\downarrow\uparrow|
\right)
$$
$$
=\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0\\
0 & -1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)\;,
$$
which is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{4}-\vec S_1\cdot \vec S_2\;,
$$
in this same basis. (And of course, both are diagonal in the $jm$ basis.)